# Default number of rows in laravel collective form

Tags: laravel, forms

When I use laravel collective form,It's set by default **`rows="10"`** and **`cols="50"`**. How can i overcome this issue of default number of **`rows`** and **`cols`**??
I don't want to set default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options (third parameter) array is actually the attributes array of that element, you so can just pass any `'key' => 'value'` and the element will have it as attributes, like below example for textarea:

```
{!! Form::textarea('DescribeYourSelf',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'rows' => 2, 'cols' => 30]) !!}
```

hope this is what you want

Comment: no i don't want to set any value for rows. but when I left it, set default 10 i also don't need that

Comment: you don't want to set any value and also not want it set by default value ?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: but that not how things work. There has to be some value's ,i think

Comment: what if we set `rows=>'auto'`?

Comment: as much i know there is no 'auto' value exist either it set default or you can customised it by above methhod

Comment: if above answer solve your query them mark it . @HirenPipariya